# Jquery slide effect not working as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

Hi im trying to make a slide effect for a certain text and the sliding effect ads something like additional margin.'

The effect: [like margin or something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRSZp.png),
the framework is http://materializecss.com/.

The question: Is there any possibility to hide this "margin"?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.collapse1').hover(function(){
    $('.collapsetext1').animate({
        width: 'show',
    }, 444);
});
```

});

Comment: can you have a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem that you facing.

Comment: Without your HTML or a demo it's not clear at all what you're asking.

Comment: I did place a photo of what is happening cant do it on jsfiddle becuse it dosn't have this framework to work with. I want the gray to be just on the text and img not bellow it either

Comment: the photo is "like margin or something"*

Comment: http://marmolada.comule.com/marmoladacomule/

Answer (score 0):

"Like margin or something".

I dont quite know what this means. Put if you are animating elements on based on  "hover", you don't require jQuery.

```
.collapse1 {
    margin: 10px;
    transition: margin .5s linear;
}

.collapse1:hover {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

This will transition the margin on .callapse1 between 10px and 0px when it's hovered :)

Comment: Ok my mistake here is the online version http://marmolada.comule.com/marmoladacomule/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make a sliding effect for the text without having any margin ,
you really do not need to rely on jQuery :(Pure JS is enough with a little bit of CSS)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div#box1 {  
    width: 400px;   
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: -400px;
}
</style>
<script>
function slideIn(el){
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    elem.style.transition = "left 0.5s ease-in 0s";
    elem.style.left = "0px";
}
function slideOut(el){
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    elem.style.transition = "left 0.5s ease-out 0s";
    elem.style.left = "-400px";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="slideIn('box1');">slide in</button>
<button onmouseover="slideOut('box1');">slide out</button>
<div id="box1">Content in box 1 ...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can now call the functions any time not necessarily on a button click.
 So yeah , good to go .
You can refer [this](https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Trigger-CSS-Transitions-to-Control-Animations) (video tutorial) link if you want an explanation .

Comment: http://marmolada.comule.com/marmoladacomule/ the problem <--- hover on the 1st menu element

Comment: Could you explain your problem to me in detail ?

Comment: When you hover the first IMG on the menu it has the hover effect but the hover element comes out of menu and is on the menu and a little bellow it and i want it to be just one menu (the li element).

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery selector .css to change any css style

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.collapse1').hover(function() {
        $('.collapsetext1').css("margin", "");

    });
});
```

Comment: http://marmolada.comule.com/marmoladacomule/# online version of the problem hover the first element on the menu it appers to go a bit bellow with the hover effect i want it to not do so.